# How to interpret SVM for regression?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, svm

I made a regression model with SVM and applied the RBF kernel, my data exceeds 7 dimensions. the value of my MSE: 36,069 for the problem I'm solving is a low error, but my R-Square is very low R2: 0.30

Is it okay for me to evaluate my SVM with R-square, since my data is not in 2D?

Comment: For Machine Learning, also consider other sites of the StackExchange network that may be a better fit. See some suggestions here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms

Comment: You never want to evaluate any models by a single metric, especially R2 as it is often misinterpreted even when it is being used correctly.